# ASP.NET MVC - Why should I bother?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This isn't a troll, but a genuine question.

I've spent a lot of time writing 'regular' ASP.NET but I now feel compelled to ask, should I really worry about learning MVC? Or would I, given the news coming out of //build/, be better off learning XAML?

-- 
Curious of Grantham

Comment: Thanks to all who commented before the question got shut down. I'll do some more research on MVC.

Answer (score 4):

To answer a question with a question - why *wouldn't* you learn it?

---

But more seriously - and apart from the fact that it is the new sexy and many shops and developers are trying to move towards it (which should be a good reason to learn it as well):

- MVC is easier to test, since the UI and model are separated.
- MVC keeps you closer to the HTML. Webforms is a very leaky abstraction. If you ever tried to interact with server side generated elements using javascript, you know part of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Because ASP.Net MVC allows you to develop Web Applications without dealing with an artificial object oriented abstraction layer superimposed over the web that becomes a nuisance in practice the more complex your projects becomes.

Comment: "Pow ! Right in the kisser !" - Well said @Oliver !

Comment: I strongly agree as someone doing maintenance for the last couple weeks on a Web Forms site after working with ASP.NET MVC for 1.5 years. This was my first introduction to Web Forms and I think it is going to be my last.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not paint myself into a corner and learn XAML only.
The pattern for MVC is a great pattern to learn and be aware of. The MVC pattern is a common pattern that is being used in more than just the .net world so adding it to your toolbox would be beneficial to you. If you don't want to continue learning new patterns and practices, then you might as well quit coding.

Answer (score 1):

Mvc falls in line with the web paradigm and the stateless nature of http transactions. 
Mvc allows you to write extremely clean and maintainable markup.

I switched because I am passionate about .NET technologies but I always thought web forms was a bit too bloated for most scenarios.

It's also hugely dependent on personal preference since you can achieve the same goals with web forms or MVC...

Answer (score 0):

It's just cleaner and you don't wind up, up to your waist in work around webforms code to accomplish a simple task.

I mean it seems obvious to most programmers I talk to, but if you prefer webforms, then stick with that.